# Valid, working domain gives "socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Tags: python, sockets, oauth-2.0, python-requests, urllib

I'm working on a project in which I need to implement SSO. My SSO OAuth2 credentials are along the lines of:

```
SECRET = 'abcdefghijklmn12345678'
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2"
USER_API_URL = "https://myprovider.example.com/idp/userinfo.openid"
JWKS_URL = "https://myprovider.example.com/pf/JWKS"
REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost/api/1/auth/ping"
AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://myprovider.example.com/as/authorization.oauth2"
```

The library I am using has been tested and should work, but for some reason fails with:

```
[2018-09-13 14:09:29,796] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/1/auth/ping [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 59, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 314, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc15ed415f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/www/lemur/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myprovider.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /as/token.oauth2?grant_type=authorization_code&scope=openid+email+profile&code=abcdef123-ghijklm456&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fapi%2F1%2Fauth%2Fping&client_id=lemur (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc15ed415f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

After a bit of debugging, I found that the exception stems from `r = requests.post(access_token_url, headers=headers, params=params, verify=verify_cert)` within the the SSO library.

I printed out the value of `access_token_url`, which was `https://myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2`.

Some Googling informed me that `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` may stem from the fact that it was expecting a hostname rather than a URL, ie just `myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2` (without the `https://`). The hostname `myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2` does not go anywhere, and visiting it on a browser returns a "Could not receive respoonse" message. Visiting `https://myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2` works just fine, however.

My provider requires `https://` in front (ex `https://myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2`), otherwise I'll receive a "Could not receive response" message from the browser. Even appending port 443 as `myprovider.example.com:443/as/token.oauth2` will not work. `http://myprovider.example.com` does not redirect to `https`, either, and returns the "Could not receive response" message.

Parsing out the `https://` so `access_token_url = 'myprovider.example.com/as/token.oauth2'` fails as well.

Could the required use of `https://` (or, more likely, the inability to go without it) be the issue?

Thanks!